# Sorting a dataset in a loop in SAS

Tags: sorting, sas

I have a dataset like so:

id1 id2

a   a

b   b

b   c

c   d

c   e

d   f

e   g

e   h

I need to sort it like so:

id1 id2

a   a

b   b

c   d

d   f

e   g

b   c

c   e

e   h

In reality this step is a smaller set in a much larger program dealing with lab test samples. I do not have any coding attempts. I know that PROC SORT cannot do this, because the end result dataset I want is not technically "sorted". Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you put the logic behind your sort in a couple of sentences? I'm not immediately seeing the reasoning behind it.

Comment: So I want (if a,a,b,b) to sort to (a,b,a,b). I don't want id1 to repeat in the order the dataset has the observations in. Sorting by id2 could have id1 repeat. Sorting by id1 is the original state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment, it sounds like you would want the first ID2 from each ID1, before you move on to the second version of each ID1 value.  I am not sure why you would want to do this (and it is just begging for problems to crop up) but, I think this would work:

```
data dataset; input id1 $ id2 $;
cards;
a a
b b
b c
c d
c e
d f
e g
e h
;
run;

proc sort data=dataset;
  by id1 id2;
run;

data dataset; set dataset;
  by id1 id2;
  if first.id1 then count=0;
  count+1;
run;

proc sort data=dataset;
  by count id1 id2;
run;
```

It produces the result you want on your sample data.

Comment: Precisely what I was looking for. I did not think of using a third variable to sort. Thank you!